# Set transparent background of an imageview on Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am using a web view in which I am adding an image view. How can I set the background of this image view to transparent?

I have tried this:

```
mImageview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.trans);
```

Where `trans` → `<color name="trans">#00000000 </color>`.

Comment: This can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445085/understanding-colors-in-android-6-characters/11019879#11019879

Comment: I set #00000000 and it is transparent totally. Maybe there is some other error in your code?

Answer (score 622, accepted):

In your XML set the `Background` attribute to any colour, `White(#FFFFFF)` shade or `Black(#000000)` shade. If you want transparency, just put 80 before the actual hash code:

```
#80000000
```

This will change any colour you want to a transparent one.. :)

Comment: @Harshad: Is it possible to set, say, a 40% transparency for a background image set with `View.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.something)`?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit I found this link where you need to multiply by 0.4(40/100) to your RGB value. Not sure if this is helpful but you can give it a try. http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1730&t=223940

Comment: @Harshad: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer. I don't have any RGB value, but a TextView with a background image that I want to be, say, 50% transparent. But, anyway, I found the answer here in stackoverflow: `View.getBackground().setAlpha(50)`. Couldn't be simpler, right? :o) Anyway, thanks for your help!!

Comment: If you add any number from 01 to 99 before the actual hash code, it will give you the transparency. 

Eg: Black with more transparency -  `#10000000`
    Black with less transparency -  `#99000000`

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp Not only from 01 to 99, as the rest of the numbers these are also hexadecimal so you can put anything from 00 to ff. For fifty percent transparent you should put 80 instead of 50, and for the others you have some basic calculations to do...

Comment: I had #4e4747 as the RGB value which used to give me solid brown color. Changing it to #804e4747 is giving me black color with little transparency. why ?

Comment: try Color.TRANSPARENT

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to apply a gradient to an imageview so I had to set 80 to both the gradient and the background of the imageview.

Comment: It is worth noting that this doesn't make it fully transparent. Use #00000000 instead if that's what you're going for.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno May be it is working but it doesn't have anything behind it. Try to overlap the views to see if it is working.

Comment: this should help, what u should choose between "FF" and "00". https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-a-background-20-transparent-on-android

Answer (score 674):

You can set the background transparent of any layout, any view, or any component by adding this code in XML:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: I had an issue on older versions of Android that didn't handle #ff000000 as pure transparent. Using this fixed it.

Comment: Probably because #FF 00 00 00 = 100% black.

Comment: @Ioeschg The first 2 letters are for the alpha channel. #00xxxxxx would be transparent, whereas x is any hex value you want.

Comment: And the equivalent programatically if somebody is interested is Android.Resource.Color.Transparent :)

Comment: This shows as pure black on my app if i run it on the emulator using API 16 or 4.1.1. Any other workaround?

Comment: @undroid try `android:background="#00ffffff"`

Comment: try Color.TRANSPARENT

Comment: I get `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:statusBarColor' with value '@color/transparent').` when I try this

Answer (score 189):

In addition to what Harshad mentioned:

Two hexadecimal characters can be appended to any hexadecimal color code. The first two characters in an 8-digit hex color code represents its opacity in Android.

The two hexadecimal characters can range from 00 to FF. For example,

- Normal opaque black hex- "#000000"
- Fully transparent - "#00000000"
- Fully opaque - "#FF000000"
- 50% transparent - "#7F000000"

This way you can change any color to any level of transparency.

To find the hexadecimal prefix from a percentage:

Divide the percentage number by 100 and multiply by 255 to get the decimal value. Convert the decimal to hexadecimal [here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter).

For example, for 50%, 50/100 * 255 = 127. Using the link we get hexadecimal value 7F.

Source: *[Android: how to create a transparent or opaque background](http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/android-how-to-create-transparent-or-opeque-background/)*

Comment: actually, perfect 50% transparency is 7F and not 80 ;)

Answer (score 185):

If you want to add 20% or 30% transparency, you should pre-pend two more characters to the hexadecimal code, like CC.

#### Note

`android:background="#CCFF0088"` in XML

where CC is the alpha value, FF is the red factor, 00 is the green factor, and 88 is the blue factor.

### Some opacity code:

#### Hex Opacity Values

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5%  — 0D
0% —  00
```

You can also set opacity programmatically like:

```
yourView.getBackground().setAlpha(127);
```

Set opacity between 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (completely opaque). The 127.5 is exactly 50%.

You can create any level of transparency using the given formula. If you want half transparent:

```
 16 |128          Where 128 is the half of 256.
    |8 -0         So it means 80 is half transparent.
```

And for 25% transparency:

```
16 |64            Where 64 is the quarter of 256.
   |4 -0          So it means 40 is quarter transparent.
```

Comment: This answer should be mark is the best. Thanks bro <3

Answer (score 67):

Use the below code for black:

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Now if you want to use opacity then you can use the below code:

```
<color name="black">#99000000</color>
```

And the below for opacity code:

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Answer (score 29):

There is already a predefined constant. Use `Color.TRANSPARENT`.

Comment: Use of a constant should be the best/cleanest way to go about it! But in this case, the value of `Color.TRANSPARENT` is set to `0x00000000` (not the expected fully opaque `0xFF000000`), so depending on how you go about it, this constant might not really help accomplishing transparency! Still +1 for recommending a constant!

Answer (score 25):

There is already a transparent built into Android: R.color.transparent. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#transparent

But I think you may want to make the background of the image that you are placing into the WebView transparent, for example, with a transparent PNG, rather than the ImageView background. If the actual image is not at all see-through then the ImageView background can't be seen through it.

Comment: the image is transparent..it didnt hav any background..i hv also tried setting imageview background as u hv said..but it didnt work...plz help..

Comment: Can you post some more details such as a link to the image you are using and the code and layout you are using?

Answer (score 23):

**Try this code :)**

Its an fully transparent hexa code - **"#00000000"**

Answer (score 20):

In case you want it in code, just:

```
mComponentName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
```

Answer (score 15):

In your XML file, set an attribute "Alpha"

such as

```
android:alpha="0.0" // for transparent
android:alpha="1.0" // for opaque
```

You can give any value between 0.0 to 1.0 in decimal to apply the required transparency. For example, 0.5 transparency is ideal for disabled component

Answer (score 13):

**In xml**

```
@android:color/transparent
```

**In code**

```
mComponentName.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

Answer (score 12):

Or, as an alternate, parse the resource ID with the following code:

```
  mComponentName.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: is there an equivalent for androidX like **androidx**.R.color.transparent?

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio it is very simple to adjust color and opacity using a built-in tool:

[image: Android Adjust Color Opacity]

Comment: just click on it. @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still facing this problem, you may try this

`element.getBackground().setAlpha(0);`

Comment: I get a `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setAlpha(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: try to watch your `element` see if it's a null object

Answer (score 5):

Use the following for complete transparency:

```
#00000000
```

When I tried with #80000000 I got a black transparent overlay which I don't want. Try to change the first two digits; it controls the level of transparency, like

```
#00000000
#10000000
#20000000
#30000000
```

Comment: perfect color on transparent dark

Answer (score 5):

One more simple way:

```
mComponentName.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another working option I came across is to set `android:background="@null"`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `View.setAlpha(float)` to change the visibility precisely.

0 would be transparent, 1 fully visible. ;)

Comment: That changes the View's alpha, NOT its background!

Comment: The whole view will then be transparent including the content/picture in it, your setting the alpha which is wrong in this case. The user want's to keep the transparency of an Image not change the Image to be transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following code. It will help you in full or more.

1. A .xml file designed to use this code to set background color:

   ```
   android:background="#000000"
   ```

   or

   ```
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
   ```

   [image: Image is here]

   Or you can set it programmatically as well.
2. Also you can use this code programmatically:

   ```
   image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
       R.drawable.llabackground));
   ```
3. Also this code for setting the background color as well programmatically:

   ```
   image.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
   ```
4. This code for the same programmatically:

   ```
   image.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(Color.WHITE));
   ```

The color depends on your choice of which color you want to use for transparent. Mostly use a white or #FFFFFF color.

Regarding `R.drawable.llabackground`: This line of code is for your style of the background, like something special or different for your purpose. You can also use this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a drawable XML image you can make it transparent as shown in the picture below, or you can use a color code:

```
<color name="black">#99000000</color>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Color definitions with transparency information may be in the form

`#AARRGGBB` or `#ARGB`.

You can use also the shorter value for full transparency:
  **#0000**.

Other values are e.g.:

```
white  grey   black
#FFFF  #F888  #F000 - full color
#EFFF  #E888  #E000
#DFFF  #D888  #D000
#CFFF  #C888  #C000
#BFFF  #B888  #B000
#AFFF  #A888  #A000
#9FFF  #9888  #9000
#8FFF  #8888  #8000
#7FFF  #7888  #7000
#6FFF  #6888  #6000
#5FFF  #5888  #5000
#4FFF  #4888  #4000
#3FFF  #3888  #3000
#2FFF  #2888  #2000
#1FFF  #1888  #1000
#0FFF  #0888  #0000 - full transparency
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#aa000000
```

For transparency 000000 = black, you can change these six numbers for the color you want.

Comment: what is your resource to use aa before color hex

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView.setBackground(R.drawable.my_background);

ImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary);

ImageView.getImageAlpha();

ImageView.setAlpha(125); // transparency
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

use RelativeLayout which has 2 imageViews in . and set transparency code on the top imageView.

transparency code :

```
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<gradient android:startColor="#40000000"   android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:angle="270"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Convert Percentage to hex using any online tool & than simply add it on front of color value

Example: using https://www.joshuamiron.com/percent-to-hex-converter

[image]

80% opacity would be

```
 <color name="opaque_80_percent">#CC000000</color>
```