# How can I make an image transparent on Android?

Tags: android, transparency

I am using a linear layout and frame layout. In the linear layout I keep an image as background and in the frame layout I keep an imageView. In that imageView I give an image.

Now I want to make the second image (that is in the imageView) transparent. How can I do this?

Comment: you need set transparent from code or xml?

Comment: can you tell me how i can set a transparent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Try this:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
myImage.setAlpha(127); //value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque.
```

**Note**: `setAlpha(int)` is deprecated in favor of `setAlpha(float)` where 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque. Use it like: `myImage.setAlpha(0.5f)`

Comment: setAlpha(int) is deprecated in favor of setAlpha(float) where 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque `myImage.setAlpha(0.5f);`

Answer (score 106):

[`android:alpha`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha) does this in XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blah"
    android:alpha=".75"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Set an id attribute on the ImageView:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myImage"
```

In your code where you wish to hide the image, you'll need the following code.

First, you'll need a reference to the ImageView:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
```

Then, set Visibility to GONE:

```
myImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you want to have code elsewhere that makes it visible again, just set it to Visible the same way:

```
myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

If you mean "fully transparent", the above code works. If you mean "partially transparent", use the following method:

```
int alphaAmount = 128; // Some value 0-255 where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque
myImage.setAlpha(alphaAmount);
```

Comment: now also transparency is not working. when i am set visibility as GONE,it is working same as invisible

Comment: edited code sample to support partial transparency.  I misunderstood the original question

Answer (score 5):

If you are in an XML file, use the following to make your imageview transparent!

```
 android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 5):

On newer versions of Android (post Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) at least), the setAlpha(int value) method is depreciated. Instead, use the `setAlpha(float value)` method that takes a float between 0 and 1 where 0 is complete transparency and 1 is no transparency.

Answer (score 4):

Set transparency using `setAlpha(float alpha)`. The below code works for me were I used an alpha value in float, 0 - 1.

- 0: Full Transparent
- 0.5 - 50%: Transparent
- 1: Full Opaque

  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
  imageView.setAlpha(.80f);

Answer (score 4):

As setAlpha int has been deprecated, setImageAlpha (int) can be used

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_image);
img.setImageAlpha(127); //value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque.
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `setAlpha(int)` from the type ImageView is deprecated.

Instead of

```
image.setImageAlpha(127);
//value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque.
```

Answer (score 2):

In XML, use:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 2):

Image alpha sets just opacity to ImageView which makes Image blurry, try adding tint attribute in ImageView

```
 android:tint="#66000000"
```

It can also be done programatically :

```
imageView.setColorFilter(R.color.transparent);
```

where you need to define transparent color in your colors.xml

```
<color name="transparent">#66000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

For 20% transparency, this worked for me:

```
Button bu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
bu.getBackground().setAlpha(204);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setAlpha(150); // Value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent
                     // and 255 is fully opaque. Set the value according
                     // to your choice, and you can also use seekbar to
                     // maintain the transparency.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in your XML file by this code:

```
android:alpha="0.85"
```

It will make your image 15% transparent. 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque