# radiobutton change text color

Tags: android, android-text-color

I cant change the text color in my radiobutton:

```
  <RadioGroup
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:color = "#000000"
                    >

                        <RadioButton 
                            android:id="@+id/contact_yes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:color = "#000000"
                            android:text="@string/yes" />

                        <RadioButton 
                            android:id="@+id/contact_no"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:color = "#000000"
                            android:text="@string/no" />
                </RadioGroup>
```

It's always white, and I would like to change to black?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```

**or**

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

use `textColor`  to change color of text

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/contact_yes"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:color = "#000000"
android:text="@string/yes" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is `textColor="#ffff00ff"`  for example

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<RadioButton 
android:id="@+id/contact_yes"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="@string/yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use android:textColor method to do that.

An example is android:textColor="#00000000"

In #00000000 the two left bit is transparent bit .  #00 (**transparent**) 00 (**Red** Color) 00 (**Green** color) 00  (**Blue** color). they are hex.

**To more details about transparent bit see [Set transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android).**