# Android change widget drawable opacity

Tags: android, drawable, background-color, opacity, android-resources

I want to change the widget background opacity, which is defined by a drawable including a color code, programmatically in the onEnabled method.

This is the drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

I want to change the color opacity programmatically, how can I do that? I already tried using:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.widget_shape);
drawable.setAlpha(80);
```

But without success

Comment: Try solid color prefix alpha like #80FFFFFF

Comment: I want it to be chageable by the user in the config screen, so setting it in the drawable is not an option

Comment: Then create shape programmatically,  or try to call invalidate bitmap after applying alpha

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Actually it is big task create Rect programmatically positing Rect etc, you can try simple 
yourView.getBackground().setAlpha(45);

Comment: And how should I use this method in the widget? you have to change views using remoteviews

Comment: Oh! for widget you should try http://stackoverflow.com/a/28207221/1881611