# Dialog has rounded corners but not transparent edges

Tags: android, dialog

I've got the dialog below that shows up on my app... As you can see I have the rounded corners i want but i want to remove the black for transparent edges.

Here is the style xml and image of the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:insetBottom="-1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/base" />
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="20dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" />
        <stroke android:color="#7F7F7F" 
                android:width="1dp" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `<solid android:color="@color/base" />` with `<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />`

Comment: @nKn no that makes the whole thing black

Comment: I guess this might help but it implies hardcoding the background color: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: @nkn Cannot since i'm already setting the background with the xml, however the answer below did the trick.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto the solid color is the fill color of the shape. In this case it is white.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll mark this as the answer once i've waited the time required

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler if you already use a custom theme for your dialog. Like below (only the necessary item is shown):

```
 <style name="NoBlackDefaultBackground" parent="@android:style/android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/transparent_background</item>       
</style>
```

Where you create a a custom 9 patch transparent_background.png