# Transparent View over Linear Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am making an android application where I need to place a transparent view over a `LinearLayout`. See in the screenshot View where "04" is written is transparent but not completely. Any idea to make this view transparent with some color.

[image]

I made the `LinearLayout` with rounded and set the color also.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thirdLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/secondRelativeLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/clock_check_in_rounded_drawable"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >     

</LinearLayout>
```

clock_check_in_rounded_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/cyan_text_color" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Look at Aaron's answer here [transperancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XML set Background attribute to any colour White(#FFFFFF) shade or Black(#000000) shade.if you want transparancy just put 80 before the actual hash code.

```
#80000000
```

If you add any number from 01 to 99 before the actual hash code, it will give you the transparency. Eg: Black with more transparency -  #10000000 Black with less transparency -  #99000000

Comment: but see where "04" in the screenshot is written is not complete transparent view.

Answer (score 6):

Before I answer your question, lets see about the html color codes:

- Black: #000000
- Translucent Black: ##55000000
- Transparent Black: ##FF000000

  SO here the first two digits specify the transparency of the color.You can have values from **00** to **FF** for complete transparency.

Answer (score 1):

All Views in android have property Alpha , So if you want to make view fully transparent or partially transparent you can add alpha value between 0 to 1 in to alpha attribute in XML file

```
 <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#006549"
    android:alpha="0"
    android:id="@+id/instruction_text_view" />
```

OR add Alpha value to any view dynamically from java Code like below:

`backButton.setAlpha(0.2F);`