# Toolbar with Gradient Background set title background transparent

Tags: android

I defined a Gradient Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:endColor="#2F3F59"
        android:startColor="#4078A7"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

And I set it on my Toolbar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background_blue</item>
</style>
```

This is working! **BUT**:

[image]

This is what happens with the title. It gets the same gradient. This looks really ugly so I have to change this. How can I set the background of that info text to be transparent?

Comment: check this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android

Comment: Hello. I dont think that this can help me. I doubt that the title is an ImageView and i also dont know how to access the background of the title of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to disable the title of the toolbar:

```
this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and to add a custom `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also solve this by setting the background of the toolbar to your drawable.

`mToolbar().setDrawable(R.drawable.your_gradient)`

Answer (score 0):

link - [Set transparent background of an imageview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-in-android)

use this color in your color xml file and then give this color to your startcolor and end color

Comment: This is totally wrong. I dont want my toolbar to be transparent.... i want the background of the title to be transparent......

Comment: i sayed that just create translate color which you can use any where

Comment: and how to access the background of the title of the toolbar? Thats the core problem. setting a transparent background ist not the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the background color to transparent in the style section should fix the issue

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

The question [How to make title background transparent on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056068/how-to-make-title-background-transparent-on-android-app) had similar issue above solution did the trick. The android app was for Renesas RX130 and Texas Instrument CC2650 BLE solution. Bellow is solution after the fix.

[image]