# How to make title background transparent on android app

Tags: java, android

There is an issue in the follow Android App where guidance is greatly appreciated. This application is to support a Renesas RX130 microcontroller and Texas Instrument CC2650 Bluetooth Low Energy hardware demonstration design. In the initial device scanning page the tile has a bright red background as shown below.

[image]

The tool bar has a Purple to Red gradient background.

**Question:** How can the Red Tile background be made transparent?

The application has two activities. Below are excepts from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
    <activity android:name="capsense.application.rx130_cc2650.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="capsense.application.rx130_cc2650.DeviceControlActivity"/>
    <service android:name="capsense.application.rx130_cc2650.BLE_Service" android:enabled="true" />
```

Code from `activity_main.xml`, `listitem.xml`, `toolbar.xml` and `MainActivity.java` generated the first activity. Relevant sections of code is from the files are below.

Excepts from `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Excepts from `toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background_rx130_cc2650"
app:popupTheme="@style/CustomerPopUpMenuStyle"
app:theme="@style/CustomerToolbarStyle"
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Excepts from `MainActivity.java`

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(capsense.application.rx130_cc2650.R.layout.activity_main);

    mScanning = false;

    //Get User Interface Elements
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(capsense.application.rx130_cc2650.R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_label);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The complete project is available on github [Android_Mobile_App_RX130_CC2650](https://github.com/mahengunawardena/Android_Mobile_App_RX130_CC2650)

---

**References**:

- [Set transparent background of an imageview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-on-android)
- [Toolbar with Gradient Background set title background transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817109/toolbar-with-gradient-background-set-title-background-transparent/28835131#28835131)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict in color from multiple source to background.

Don't use `theme` unless if needed, as

> - **theme** influence all the views and layouts inside the toolbar
> - **style** influence only the toolbar and does not interfere with views and layouts inside toolbar

Please try below options, one of which might work for you,

**Option 1 (preferred):** update `CustomerToolbarStyle` code as below

```
<style name="CustomerToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_launcher_background_rx130_cc2650</item>
        <item name="android:title">@color/colorforeground</item>
 </style>
```

update `toolbar.xml` code as below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:popupTheme="@style/CustomerPopUpMenuStyle"
    style= "@style/CustomerToolbarStyle"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

**Option 2:** set transparent background in `CustomerToolbarStyle`

```
<style name="CustomerToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- set background color to transperant -->
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:title">@color/colorforeground</item>
    </style>
```

**Option 3:** remove `android:background` from the `CustomerToolbarStyle`

```
<style name="CustomerToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    
        <item name="android:title">@color/colorforeground</item>
</style>
```

**Option 4:** remove `app:theme="@style/CustomerToolbarStyle"` from `toolbar.xml`

If above options not working, please check below links

- [Change Toolbar background color programmatically does not change Toolbar Title Background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464078/change-toolbar-background-color-programmatically-does-not-change-toolbar-title-b/35519105)
- [Text background issue on Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639415/text-background-issue-on-toolbar)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I used option 2. BTW `android:background` needs an extra `0`. Thank you for checking out the github post develop a response.