# make background of bitmap transparent android when send its Uri to another activity

Tags: android, bitmap

here I am making a bitmap that its background is transparent but it dose not works and make background black:

```
    Bitmap baseBitmap = null;
    Canvas canvas;
    Bitmap mergedBitmap = null;
    baseBitmap = imageViewToBitmap(imgForground);
    mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseBitmap.getWidth(), baseBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    canvas = new Canvas(mergedBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap((baseBitmap), matrix, null);
```

and here is the function I use to extract bitmap out of imageview:

```
public Bitmap imageViewToBitmap(ImageView imageView) {
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getMinimumWidth(), drawable.getMinimumHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

send it to other activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EditImageActivity.this, FilterImageActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uri", getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmap).toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

and the function getImageUri is :

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
    imgForground.setImageBitmap(inImage);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

in the other activity using getintent the image background it black:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();

   Uri uri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("uri"));
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-on-android

Answer (score 2):

You created Bitmap with RGB_565 option.

```
mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseBitmap.getWidth(), baseBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); // your code
```

It's not support transparent, so you need to use ARGB_8888 for transparent.

```
Canvas canvas;
Bitmap mergedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(baseBitmap.getWidth(), baseBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // changed code
Bitmap baseBitmap = imageViewToBitmap(imgForground);
canvas = new Canvas(mergedBitmap);
canvas.drawColor(0);
canvas.drawBitmap(baseBitmap, matrix, null);
```

Comment: it doesn't change the result. background is black.

Comment: you need canvas.drawColor(0); code before draw bitmap. updated answer.

Comment: I edit the question, the problem is in sending png via intent and uri to anther activity.

Comment: You can send bytearray via Intent to another activity.

Comment: Wang is sending by bytearray make its size more? is it good to send image via bytearray or uri?

Comment: uri is safe more, but speed is slow, and you can use file path also. you can save bitmap to file instead db.

Comment: I dont want to save file before. because it needed permission

Answer (score 2):

add the following to make the background transparent,

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```

Comment: I edit the question, the problem is in sending png via intent and uri to anther activity.