# Semi-transparent background of toolbar and statusbar

Tags: android, background, toolbar, statusbar, transparent

Hello According to the image above, I want to make my toolbar and status bar white so that the background can be seen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJdTJ.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqB3k.jpg)

Comment: have you tried setting opacity value to .5 or 50% for the toolbar/appbar ?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a color that's a lower opacity version of the color you're using. So if you have a white in your colors.xml that's `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` you can have a transparent white that's 75% white: `<color name="transparent_white">#BFFFFFFF</color>`

This is a good reference: [Set transparent background of an imageview on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492554/set-transparent-background-of-an-imageview-on-android)